# How to add the effect of skewness in the portfolio optimisation objective function?

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, markowitz, skewness, scenario-analysis

I have the following risk adjusted portfolio which I optimise,

[image]

where gamma is the risk return trade off, $r$ are the returns and $C$ is the covariance matrix which considers scenarios, so it is not defined as $r^\top r$, but as shown in the following Markowitz paper (page 3, $C = D + GPG'$): https://www.jstor.org/stable/2327552?seq=1

$P$ is a diagonal $SxS$ matrix with the probability

$G$ is an $NxS$ matrix whose entries are given by $=−$. Where $$ are the returns of the assets and $$ are the returns of the nth asset class weighted by the probabilities of the scenarios. $N$ total numer of assets

$D$ is a diagonal $NxN$ matrix whose entries are given by $=Σ^S_s
*()^2$. Where $$ is the standard deviation of the nth asset for the sth scenario

Now I want to add also the third moment thus the skewness to this optimisation function, but I do not really know how, and if I have to include the scenarios in this skewness and how.

Can you guide me pls? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to maximize or minimize portfolio skewness?

Comment: this is a very good question..actually I do not really know..they are both acceptable I guess for returns. what is the typical way of thinking about it? many thanks for your answer

Comment: The link requires login. Edit your question describing the scenario adjustment to $C$

Comment: Without delving into the the scenario bit, one possible approach to adding higher order distribution properties (i.e. skew) is to consider the Nth order Taylor expansion of a utility function and then taking it from there... Of course, this may result in a lot of ugly (corner) cases, but nevertheless it is a starting point...

Comment: I edited the question with info on the covariance matrix. @develarist how to choose between positive and negative skewness in the optimisation function? should I look at my asset classes indiviadually to see how they are skewd and then decide? some may be positive and some negative though

Comment: @Kermittfrog as the returns are not really gaussian, I should expect to get a more realistic results if I include the third moment, is it right?

Comment: notwithstanding the scenario adjustment, become familiar with the co-skewness matrix used to calculate portfolio skewness http://www.quantatrisk.com/2013/01/20/coskewness-and-cokurtosis/

Comment: thanks for this post, that's the way I also found in literature to find the coskewness matrix..In this paper " Boudt, Cornilly, Verdonck, A coskewness shrinkage approach for estimating the skewness of linear combinations of random variables"..available for free. Here they maximize the skewness but it is not clear why they decided to maximise rather than minimize..

Comment: A positive skewness induces more frequent 'positive extremes' (compared to a symmetric distribution.)

Comment: @Kermittfrog if portfolio weights are optimized so that the portfolio returns have *in-sample* positive skewness, how do those weights hold-up upon the realization of *out-of-sample* portfolio skewness? In other words, how reliable is an in-sample estimate of returns skewness relative to actual out-of-sample skewness, as discussed in https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58400/is-asset-return-skewness-hard-to-estimate

Comment: @develarist I have answered that question. Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: It don't see an answer there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's derive a *possible* approach from utility theory.

Our investor is risk averse and exhibits CARA utility using an exponential utility function with risk aversion parameter $\gamma>0$ (risk averse agent):

$$u(x)=\frac{1-e^{-\gamma x}}{\gamma}$$

A 3rd order Taylor series expansion around $x=0$ yields

\begin{align}
u(x)\approx&  x - \frac{1}{2}\gamma x^2+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2x^3
\end{align}

Thus, the expected utility (which is to be maximized) is
\begin{align}
E\left[u(x)\right]&\approx E(x)-\frac{1}{2}\gamma E(x^2)+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2 E(x^3)\\
&=\mu_x-\frac{1}{2}\gamma\left(\sigma_x^2+\mu_x^2\right)+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2\left(skew_x+3\mu_x\sigma_x^2+\mu_x^3\right)
\end{align}

In a portfolio application, we can now make use of standard notation and the helpful hint from @develarist in the comments and maximize

$$
w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}\gamma w^T\Sigma w+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2 w^TM_3(w\otimes w)
$$

subject to your investment restrictions.

Effectively, this approach is (only) a starting point for incorporating skewness in your optimisation. Here, the tradeoff is clearly between $-.5\gamma$ 'penalty' for variance and a 'reward' of  $\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2$ for positive skewness. You can certainly disentangle the two and simply introduce two parameters of your choice, say $a$ and $b$ to penalize/reward portfolio variance and portfolio skewness.

Comment: thanks a lot. this is a great explanation. So actually increasing $γ$ the risk is minimise and the positive skewness is increased...if $γ$ is a vector of values from -1000 to +1000 if for each value I run my optimisation so the efficient frontier should become a surface with x volatility, y return, z skewness I could simply choose the point in the surface which I like the most (eg. max sharpe) and in turn I will have the gamma..does it sound a reasonably strategy? I do not want to impose a gamma but I want to choose the best point in the efficient frontier which will then have a certain gamma

Comment: Hi Luigi, yes to all three. 1) Your resulting surface is threedimensional, 2) varying $\gamma$ will trace out various combinations, 3) You need a concept for "optimality", i.e. which parameter $\gamma$ is ultimately to be used.

Comment: thanks..just one last point..M3 is the coskewness matrix right? if I calculate it as $E[Σ*μ]$ where sigma is not a typical covariance but my scenario based covariance, do you think the conclusion as above would stil apply?

Comment: Technically, M3 is not a matrix (anymore) but a 3D-tensor. Nevertheless, you can represent it as a (2D) matrix, of course. I am afraid that you cannot simply replace a (scenario based) covariance into the M3 matrix as it is an expectation, i.e. you must specify (scenario) expectations regarding 2nd **and** 3rd (co-)moments. Your scenario specification effort is hence $O(n^3)$.

Comment: ... by the way: The $O(n^m)$ behavior ($m$=number of moments to consider) is one of the reasons why the "moment-based-portfolio-optimization" approaches have never really taken off from academia :)

Comment: mmm I see..thanks a lot..so I guess $M_3$ like $C$, will be a combination of the matrices $P$, $D$, $G$ but just in another form to have the dimensions of a skewness..I need I guess to figure out what this form is..

Comment: @Kermittfrog do you know of a source that incorporates portfolio skewness in the objective function without starting from a (CARA) utility function of any sort? and you might be able to answer this related question on portfolio skewness' derivation: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/derivation-of-portfolio-skewness-and-portfolio-kurtosis

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting from a CARA utility function like how the other answer does, an alternative for incorporating portfolio skewness in the mean-variance model's objective function, without risk-aversion parameter $\gamma$ or going through a Taylor series expansion of some arbitrarily asserted utility function, could be

$$\arg \max_w  \enspace w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2} \left( w^T\Sigma w \right) +\frac{1}{3} \left[ w^TM_3(w\otimes w )\right], \hspace{1cm} 1_N^\top w = 1$$

where $M_3$ is the co-skewness matrix. This formulation would be suitable if investors' preferences are unknown and we don't want to assert arbitrary assumptions for investor preferences.

Comment: Hi @develariat; this *looks* very *ad hoc* to me. But adding weights to vol/skew is of course  a bit ad hoc as well. I’ll try to find some of the references this weekend. (No promises, though... :(

Comment: should the $\frac{1}{3}$ coefficient be changed to $\frac{1}{6}$?

Comment: @develarist, thanks for proposing an answer. I agree and happy with both the soluion even if the manager of the fund I am implementing this wants to have a risk aversion parameter, so i will stick to the Kermittfrog solution, however, the difficult part for me here is the definition of $M_3$ considering the fact that it has to be scenario based and should be defined in a similar manner as $C$...but so far I cannot find anything in literature :(..any idea would be very much appreciated