# Can genetic algorithm help in portfolio optimisation when convexity is not verifiable

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization, optimization, convexity, skewness

I have the following portfolio cost function to maximise:

$$
w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}\gamma w^T\Sigma w+\frac{1}{6}\gamma^2 w^TM_3(w\otimes w),
$$

which considers the co-skewness ($M_3$ tensor), $γ$ is the risk aversion (a constant), $w$ is the weigh vector which is the quantity to estimate, $\Sigma$ is the covariance and $\mu$ the returns.

Now, to understand whether this function is convex or not and choose the best optimiser, I should compute the hessian. However, I have plenty of constraints, roughly 20 on my asset weighs, so even if potentially computing the hessian of that function can be done, unfortunately by adding all those constraints will change very much the optimisation hypersurface which I guess is almost impossibile to verify convexity.

So in case I have no idea whether a cost function is convex or not, is the genetic algorithm the only choice?
What are its pros and cons for portfolio optmimisation?

Thanks.
Luigi

Comment: Since you do not have convexity you have to use heuristics such as Genetic Algorithms. @enrico-schumann has written some code and some examples of these heuristics applied to Portfolio Optimization https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3391756

Comment: ok thanks, I will have a look at it, I hope to find the answers to my 2 questions there.

Comment: the following paper has mean-variance-skewness as a multi-objective function that they also convert to a single objective function, but then they turn to a GA model http://www.cscanada.net/index.php/mse/article/download/9233/10133

Comment: thanks, I also found many here...https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324722054_Genetic_algorithm-based_portfolio_optimization_with_higher_moments_in_global_stock_markets but I requested the full text and I need to wait

Comment: i could send you Saranya Prasanna 2014. they use polynomial goal programming (PGP) to solve a mean-variance-skewness-kurtosis multi-objective optimization function (MVSK). nothing about heuristic or genetic algorithm. only cites Lai 1991 as being the first application of PGP to portfolio skewness as a work-around to the non-convexity

Comment: yes many thanks that can be of help..in the end I do not really want to stick to genetic algorithms, I just want a way to solve a mean-variance-skewness with no assumption on the convexity

Comment: If you don't really want to stick to GA, then the question title should be changed to a broader term

Comment: @noob2: thanks for suggesting the paper. @ Luigi87: How do you come up with the skewness 'cube'? If you just compute it from a dataset, there would be a simpler way to optimise portfolio skewness. [With the shown model, the resulting matrices will typically get very large; in particular, should you intend to add kurtosis to the objective function.]

Comment: @develarist Sorry but I do not agree, the question still holds for me. I still want to have an answer to those questions, then if I realise there are better way (the post asks: is the genetic algorithm the only choice?) I'd rather post a new question specificly related to another optimisation method.

Comment: @EnricoSchumann: this is the way I proceeded https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/58697/how-to-add-the-effect-of-skewness-in-the-portfolio-optimisation-objective-functi?noredirect=1#comment83846_58697, if you have a simpler way please describe it in there, thanks.

Comment: @Luigi87: I have jotted down some explanations/code at http://enricoschumann.net/notes/portfolio-selection-with-higher-moments.html Perhaps that helps.

Comment: @EnricoSchumann, thanks a lot. I appreciate the time you spent on it..honestly I do not get very well your article..especially because I use python not R. Moreover, I have no access to the book (see Gilli et al., 2019, chapter 14, for more details) so I cannot really check if this scenario optimisation is suitable for my case